# Set string values on matplotlib x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using below code I'm attempting to plot x axis values as strings with matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.xticks(fontsize=24)
plt.yticks(fontsize=24)

plt.plot( 'x', 'y', data=pd.DataFrame({'x': np.array(['a' , 'b' , 'c']) , 'y': np.array([1,2,3]) }), marker=None, color='blue')


plt.show()
```

This error is returned :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'c'
```

It appears matplotlib is inferring the axis value as string. How to change this ?

I've tried setting the type but this does not fix :

```
astype(str)
```

Comment: I don't get any error using this script

Comment: No errors here either, python 2 or 3.  Could you describe in more detail what you want the plot to look like? And also provide more of the stack trace -- is it plt.plot() that returns the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error in `python2` with `matplotlib==1.5.3`.

---

## If you are using python3

Upgrading `matplotlib` to newest can solve this problem:

```
pip3 install matplotlib --upgrade
```

---

## If you are using python2

Because the newest `matplotlib` doesn't support 2.x, you can upgrade to `matplotlib==2.1`:

```
pip2 install matplotlib==2.1
```

---

## If you don't want to upgrade

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.yticks(fontsize=24)
x = np.array(['a' , 'b' , 'c'])
xn = range(len(x))
plt.xticks(xn, x, fontsize=24)

plt.plot(xn, 'y', data=pd.DataFrame({'y': np.array([1,2,3]) }), marker=None, color='blue')
plt.show()
```